# Var_dump ACF "API"

Tags: plugins

I am using ACF (last version) with WordPress (last version too).
I need to modify the post_object fields of ACF so I use this [`acf/fields/post_object/query`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-fields-post_object-query/) function.

All works fine but when I do a var_dump in the function in the functions.php file, it's impossible to find the result anywhere :(

Does anybody know where I can find this?

My code in the functions.php

```
function member_relation($args, $field, $post) {
    var_dump($post); // This var_dump ?
    $args['post_parent'] = $post;
    return $args;
}
add_filter('acf/fields/post_object/query/name=list_cases', 'member_relation', 10, 3);
```

Comment: what happens if you `die` immediately after?

Answer (score 1):

Probably nowhere because it outputs too early. I recommend to use `error_log` function and turn on `WP_DEBUG_LOG`.

Just add to the `wp-config.php` file somewhere in front of this line:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

these new lines:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Now create in `wp-content` folder a new file `debug.log` and set chmod to 640.

And this line in your code:

```
var_dump($post);
```

replace with this:

```
error_log( var_export( $post, true ) );
```

Now you will find content of the `$post` variable in the `debug.log` file.

Comment: Thanks you for you help :) But your solution doesn't work for me. The debug.log is empty.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot write that you have to add this line to the wp-config.php too.

`define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try using die() after the dump.

```
var_dump($post); // This var_dump ?
die();
```

OR

```
print_r($post);
die();
```

Comment: *You can probably try dying.. after the dump* Whahahaha, sorry, but this sound funny. I just hope you did not meant the user must die after he took a s&!*

Comment: no no. I meant dying the code

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the post object field doesn't query any posts until the moment you open the drop down and this is happening through AJAX.

This means that in order to see the variable that you dumped, you need to open the developer tools of your browser while you are on the admin page where the field is shown, go to the network tab, try to open the dropdown and then finally, check the last call.

However, as I said this is something that is happening only in the admin. If you want to modify the value in the front-end, you should just use get_field() and manipulate the variable that it returns.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized how old the question is, you probably already solved the issue.

Comment: there is nothing to be sorry about, answers are intended to expand the general knowledge base, the fact that they also solve the question is a "bonus". Even old questions should be answered if one exists (or if existing answers are not great).